How can I see the output of the print function in flutter on a real Android device?
I am running flutter on a real device and print(), log(), debugprint() does not work.
Is there any alternative?
try {
  final email = _emailController.text;
  final password = _passwordController.text;
  final userCredential = FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
  print(userCredential);
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  log(e.code);
  debugprint(e.code);
  print(e.code);
}


Real device of what type?  iPhone/iPad - use XCode to see the logfiles.  Android devices require adb (I think) to see the logs.  If you're doing a debug tether, your logs should show up in your IDE.

android, it's doesn't show anything


Android Studio
You can see the output from Debug instead of Logcat on the sidebar or bottom bar. Furthermore, you can also tap the output region and use combination keys ctrl+F (cmd+F on MacOS) to find the text you want.
BTW, you still can use MethodChannel on Flutter to call methods in Android or Java provided with Log, Log4J, Logger or XLog and etc. in order that the print can show on Logcat.
Visual Studio Code
You can see the output from Debug Console on the bottom (left/right/top) bar (View->Debug Console) by filtering the text you want.


Review if your logcat on Android has a filter.
You can use elaborated lib to have custom logs:

https://pub.dev/packages/fimber
https://pub.dev/packages/logger

